# How to test code from nested packages

Tags: java, android, junit, mockito, android-testing

I would like to test my java code with mockito and I would **NOT** like to have all my methods being public.

My problem is the following, let's assume I have the following code:

```
package com.whatever;

public class Parent
{
    public void PlayWithChild(Child child)
    {
        child.Hug();
    }
}

package com.whatever.subpackage;

public class Child
{
    public void Hug()
    {
    }
}
```

and I have the test:

```
package com.whatever;

import com.whatever.subpackage;

public class Test
{
    @Test
    public void PlayWithChild_ChildHugged()
    {
        //Arrange
        Child mckChild = Mockito.mock(Child.class);

        //Act
        new Parent(mckChild).PlayWithChild();

        //Assert
        Mockito.verify(mckChild).Hug();
    }
}
```

Now if I make Hug method package-accessible (removing) the 'public', then I can not access it from the test... and I don't want to put everything (Parent, CHild, and my whole testable library) to the same package, I want to organize them.

Comment: Assuming you mean you *do not* want all your methods public, if Hug were package-private, how could Parent call it in production?

Comment: You're right, it can't do it either. What is the solution for this? :/ That Parent can't call Child.Hug either...

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to decide what degrees of *encapsulation and abstraction* you want your design to have. Java doesn't have a particularly granular way of specifying which components are accessible from which *other* components, so you may have to express those in documentation instead of relying on the compiler to enforce them for you.

In your case, I think you should make the `Hug` method public; if you want to make it really clear, add corresponding Javadoc or put Child into a subpackage called "internal" to discourage its casual use.

---

Java's four access levels:

- `public` access, which poses no problem to testing or mocking
- `protected` access, which includes package access and out-of-package subclasses. Testing within the same package is easy, but you may have to create manual test doubles to access/verify protected method calls from outside the package in question.
- Default or package-private access, which as you noted is easy to test/call from within the same package. From other packages, the methods don't exist in any meaningful way for calling or testing.
- `private` methods, which can't be called or tested directly.

*Why would someone make a private method in test-driven development?* Easy: Because the private method is an implementation detail that doesn't need to be tested. Likewise, `protected` or package-private methods are implementation details that don't need to be tested outside of the package. Here, if the Hug() method is public and it calls private or package-private method FeelBetter(), then callers from other packages should go only by the *public* API Hug without calling or concerning themselves with implementation details like FeelBetter().

The consequence of this is to almost encourage large, overscoped packages, because that may look to be the best way to hide irrelevant implementation details from other packages and to limit the number of entry points. It's true that putting close collaborators in the same package allows *small package APIs*, which is a good goal. With enough classes in one package, though, this notion breaks down; luckily, it only breaks down once the package is demonstrated to be *so big it merits two separate packages*, at which point you can stop and think about which components are connected and which ones can be extracted into APIs of their own. This may mean widening access for certain classes/methods from package to public, which is to be expected when splitting packages. It may also imply adding accessible getters or other state-querying methods for the sake of testing, which is also to be expected when developing testable components.

For more information about how to make testable systems, and how to interact with test doubles (or real tested components), I suggest reading Martin Fowler's article *[Mocks Aren't Stubs](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html)*.

Comment: long story short, I shall remain using public methods everywhere if I want to test them, and I want to have the classes organized nicely in a package/directory structure ? My initial goal was that my tests can access them, however someone using my JAR should not. :/

Comment: I understand that goal and am telling you that it is impossible or very difficult. The best you could do that I can think of is to make a public subclass that widens visibility of package-private methods, then put that subclass in your test JAR. Shoot for Javadoc and robust package APIs as a general rule instead.